# Quitar campos del objeto en su heredero en Typescript

Tags: typescript, herencia

Para contextualizar voy a poner un ejemplo.
En mi estructura/interfaz tengo lo siguiente:

```
export interface OBJETO {
    campo1: number,
    campo2: number,
    campo3: number
}
```

Quiero declarar un `OBJETO2`, que herede todos los campos que tiene `OBJETO` salvo `campo1`

Es decir:

```
export interface OBJETO2 extends OBJETO {
    campo4: number,
}
```

Lo que pasa con esto es que cada OBJETO2 que cree, va a tener la propiedad de `campo1`.

Mi idea para resolver esto sería crear un objeto nuevo que tenga el `campo1`, e incluirlos en los objetos que me parezcan acorde. Sería hacer lo siguiente:

```
export interface CAMPO_1 {
    campo1: number,
}

export interface CAMPO_2_y_CAMPO_3{
    campo2: number,
    campo3: number
}

export interface OBJETO extends CAMPO_1 {
}

export interface OBJETO2 extends CAMPO_2_y_CAMPO_3{
    campo4: number,
}
```

No creo que esta sea la mejor forma, siento y pienso que queda muy desorganizado y probablemente ya exista una palabra reservada u operador que simplifique todo esto.

Comment: Typescript no es lo mismo que Javascript.  Recordemos que Javascript es un lenguaje basado en prototipos mientras que Typescript incluye además de "tipos explícitos", interfaces y otras cosas que no existen en Javascript.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El operador [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) borra cualquier objeto y también puedes usarlo para borrar sus propiedades.

```js
const persona = {
   nombre: "Arriel",
   pais: "Australia",
   edad: -1
};

console.log(persona);
delete persona.edad;
console.log(persona)
```

En el caso de typescript e interfaces, **sólo puedes quitar la propiedad del objeto si está marcada como opcional.**

```
interface interface1 {
   campo1: number;
   campo2: string;
   campo3 ? : number; // marcado como opcional
   campo4: boolean;
};

const ObjetoSinCampo3: interface1 = {
   campo1 : 3,
   campo2 : 'nombre',
   campo3 : 10,
   campo4 : false
};

delete ObjetoSinCampo3.campo3;
console.log(ObjetoSinCampo3);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=4#code/AQSwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZVJWiUEZgG8BQwRSCAtgA4D2WAXMGAK6kBGsA3IcWVQEx0DOEGOADmHIsBIVKAZmAB+YHUYt2nSd0oAWOs0qUANlARhxAXw6EklMIOAB5ZgCsoESgGVwAYU0y64aHhkKBwAXjx1KSocOhkAGkjNHiVgAHIwShYYKFSEiSjZFKwABjyuaS0UxAN+KEILfEIAEygjaAdnVw9vXwA6Aplxa1tDKF6DShEACkcXN08wH2kZAEoOIA)

O puedes utilizar [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#the-omit-helper-type). Cabe destacar que `Omit` crea un tipo nuevo, que es lo que originalmente querías evitar.

```
interface interface1 {
   campo1: number;
   campo2: string;
   campo3 ? : number;
   campo4: boolean;
};

type interface2 = Omit<interface1, "campo3">

const ObjetoSinCampo3: interface2 = {
   campo1 : 3,
   campo2 : 'nombre',
   campo4 : false
};
 
console.log(ObjetoSinCampo3);
```